# Need right combination of Composite key and order

Tags: sql, indexing, composite-primary-key

I have a column HashKey which I use it in search queries but this can have duplicate values. Right now we have ID column which we made it as a Primary Key. But i wanted to change now to composite primary key

```
ALTER TABLE Events
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Events_ID_HashKey PRIMARY KEY (HashKey, ID)
```

So My question if i do search on the HashKey will it take full advantage of Cluster Index scan. Do i need to create separate non-clustered index on HashKey  column alone.

We do mostly equal number of inserts/Update and Search operations

Which one would be most useful with respect to the performance(Considering insert operation as well)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this.."if i do search on the HashKey will it take full advantage of Cluster Index scan"

Comment: I mean will it be cluster index scan ?. and also if it is cluster index then it requires rearranging data on insert. so if i go for non-clustered index will it be better than clustered index in my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your queries are trying to retrieve only hashkey,then i would recommend adding it as seperate index which would also avoid wide clustered key,the index would be of below form..

```
create index nci_test on table(hashkey)
```

There is no need to add `id` column since it is primary key and will be part of this index too ..

I won't bother about insert or update performance,until i can conclude through testing on acceptable performance levels..

Comment: i am not sure,i didn;t do downvote,if you follow this link and frame your question according to this,you are guaranteed to get amazing responses:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/